# MS Access Opening Read Only

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have designed and built a database in MS Access 2013. There is a back end file on a shared drive and multiple users use a front end located on their individual PCs.

Occasionally, seemingly randomly, the back end will lock out in read only mode, meaning that none of the front ends can update the back end, and when I open the Back End, I get the yellow bar saying:

"READ-ONLY This database has been opened read-only. You can only change data in linked tables. To make design changes, save a copy of the database".

It won't let you save a copy of the database by the way. Other databases in the same location open correctly.

I have some spreadsheets that access the database read only, occasionally these change to Share Deny Write, and when they do you get the 1kb lock file for the database. This allows me to see who has it locked out. In my case, this file doesn't appear until I open the database read only and then it shows as locked out to me.

Eventually, it tends to just fix itself, but it can take hours and I have no idea what happened to fix it!

I've searched Google and tried everything that's been suggested, and of course restarted my PC a couple of time, none of which fixed it. However, last time this happen, after restating my PC it worked again, could have been a coincidence.

Any advise about how I can see who's locked it, or how I can get it to unlock would be greatly appreciated so we don't have hours of downtime!

Comment: To diagnose which process has the file locked, I suggest Sysinternals Process Explorer, or http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ . Both will have to run on the server that hosts the shared drive, I think.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I'm afraid I work in a large business and so don't have that level of access to the server. Our firewall even blocked the URL you posted!

Comment: For Unlocker, you can just search for "Unlocker 1.9.2". But to solve this, you will probably need to have your admins look at the file, or move it to a server you *have* access to. Or live with it. :(